# Posting to database through controller using visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-ajax

I am stuck using visual studio. I have a basic understanding through the tutorials but I feel I am missing a fundamental concept. A push in the right direction would help a lot.

I need to post data from a table to the database. I have followed the MVC tutorial available in MSDN. From the tutorial I understand the following:
1)A controller is like an endpoint i.e. can be accessed through an URL.
2)A model is like a structure upon which controller performs the action.
3)View is what is rendered to the user.

I believe to post data to the database, I must first create a model which defines the nature of data and then pass the data to the controller and in the controller update and save to the database. I am following the tutorial and creating a database by scaffolding the operations. I searched for a lot of tutorials and understood the operations but as I am scaffolding I am finding it difficult to understand where exactly I must update and save to the database.

This is my Javascript:

```
var table = $('<table>').addClass('table ');
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=repos+topic:' + $(this).attr('id') +  '&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10',
        success: function (data) {

            table.empty(); 
table.append("<thead><tr><th>Avatar</th><th>Name</th><th>Score</th><th>URL</th><th>Updated at</th></tr></thead>");
            $.each(data.items, function (i, object) {
                var row = $('<tr>').addClass('table-primary');
                row.append('<td><img src=' + object.owner.avatar_url + 'height=50px width=50px/></td>')
                row.append('<td>' + object.name + '</td>' + '<td>' + object.score + '</td>' + '<td>' + object.url + '</td>' + '<td>' + object.updated_at + '</td>');
                table.append(row);

            });
            table.append('</table>');
            $('table').replaceWith(table);

            debugger
            var data = $('.table').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Movie/POST',  
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Done");
                }
            })
        }


    });

});
```

This is the Model:

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AvatarURL { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Score { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }


    }
public class gitrepoModel
{
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller:

[HttpPost]

```
public void Post(gitrepo model)
    {

        Movie mov = new Movie();
        mov.AvatarURL = model.Name;
        mov.Name = model.Name;
        mov.Score = model.Score;
        mov.UpdatedAt = model.UpdatedAt;
        MvcMovie.Models.Movie.Add(mov);



}
```

}

Based on my understanding I believe that in the second ajax function the data in the table is getting serialized-JSON format and being sent to the URL /Movie/POST-which is the controller I have defined. The controller is taking argument as a model, and the controller should hold the logic to update the database with the values and save to the database.

I have been learning Visual Studio from 3 days and am not able to understand the concepts quite well.Have no clue if this question lacks research. Lots of Help needed:p. Thank you:)

Comment: Your view should pass json data, but it seems you are passing the whole table. You don’t have a form to add/edit record ? Also you are using all jquery for rendering table, which is not necessary. You can use mvc razor view to render data

Comment: I have inserted the JSON data into the table,now I thought ,I'll just serialise the table. I don't have a form, I need to insert the entries in the table to the database.:)

Comment: you need to insert all the records in the table to database or one record ?

Comment: All the records in the table.

Comment: then your post method should take List<Movie> as the parameter and you need to build a json in that manner and send it

Comment: Also I don't see any input elements in table, how are you editing table values ?

Comment: So instead of the gitrepo model I am using as the parameter I need to use List<Movie>? How do I interact with the database? Thee CRUD operations now take care of posting and saving to the database, how do I change the create method? i.e. I don't have a form which posts input when submitted but I need to automatically send the data in the table to the database,how do I save the data I send to the post method into the database?:)

Comment: As of now how are you interacting with database ?

Comment: @Krishna what I am doing is I am generating a table through the first ajax call from which I am retrieving data through an API, I need to send this data to the database to be stored as I need it.

Comment: @Krishna Now I am trying to follow a tutorial where a new database context/entity is created and then the data is entered to the fields of the database and then saved through a save to() method. However I have no idea how what the save to() actually does, and I am not understanding how to I teract with the database through the controller.

Comment: I think you need to learn a lot which we cannot teach in this post. Try to follow the tutorial

Comment: I tried finding tutorials ,but all tutorials either deal with forms, or do not show how to interact with the database. But true ,lots lot learn. Thank you:-).

Comment: Find tutorials on either ado.net or entity framework